# How to bind a checkedlistbox from a property of an object within a list<object>?

Tags: c#

below provided code returns a List of Column class object which contains

```
List<Columns> ColumnNames = new List<Columns>();
        ColumnNames = metadataobj.GetColumns(clbTables.Items[indexofselectedtable].ToString());
```

How can i bind  a checkedlist box with the ColumnNames object ,and display only the Name property of the ColumnNames to the user? I cannot find a DataSource method for my checkedlistbox. Please Help....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just type it straightat
chklistcolumns.DataSource = ColumnNames;
 chklistcolumns.DisplayMember = "Name";
 chklistcolumns.ValueMember = "ID";